# Transferring site content from Sandbox to Production

Tags: 2013, sandbox-solution, production, deploy

So I have been tasked with taking an existing Sandboxed Sharepoint (2013) that my company uses, and transferring all the content to a Production Sharepoint (2013). I'm trying to read into it, but I feel like it is so overly complicated and I'm missing something. We literally want whatever is in the Sandbox to be exactly implemented into the new system. Is there a simple way to deploy the site?

I've been reading about exporting solutions, using Visual Studio, PowerShell, and Sharepoint designer, etc., but it seems like I'm either missing something or this is overly complicated.

Can someone explain to me why it needs to be done this way? Further more, could someone help break down the steps I need to do this so I can understand them? I've been heavily researching this, but I simply don't understand the information that I've found.

Comment: do you want to move the sandbox solution to production envirnoment or you want Site contents( list, items, libraries, files etc) to production?

Comment: I think we want to move everything. Basically, the site functions the way we want in Sandbox, and we have lots of organized content. I believe we want to copy the exact site as it is and move it over to production. I feel like there must be a way to do this fairly simply.

To be completely honest, I don't really understand what a "solution" or "sandbox solution" is. How does the sandbox differ from the production environment?

Comment: check the answer,

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just do a backup of the Content and restore to new Production site from SP Central Admin site? Havent worked in SP in 6-8 months but had done this before multiple times throughout 8+ years working with it when upgrading or fixing someone elses broken server-side upgrades.

Comment: This sounds simple enough. What do I need to do to do this? It's surprising that I haven't been able to found a very concise answer to this. I'd imagine it's something that many people would want to do.

Answer (score 0):

In this case your option is simple.

- Perform the Backup of site collection using [Backup-Spsite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901.aspx)
- Move the .bak file to production farm
- Restore the site to [Restore-Spsite.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607958.aspx) You have to give the new url of ths ite collection

You have to make sure following things

- You Sandbox farm and Production farm on the same build level
- if their is any solution/ 3rd party stuff installed in Sandbox then it should be production
- Authnetication method should be same other wise you have to migrate the users

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! We should be making the migration in the next week or so (hopefully) so I'll come back here and let you (and any others searching for this information) know if it was successful.

Comment: great, hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Tried to make this an edit to my last comment, but apparently I don't have permission.

How will I know if anything are any "solution/3rd party" things installed on the Sharepoint? I didn't make the Sandbox one, so I'm not sure.

Comment: go to central admin > system settings > farm solution...this is one place where farm level solutions installed...